# Show hidden div if textfield value is set to a certain value

Tags: javascript

I hop somebody here is able to help me out.
I would like to show a hidden div tag if a textfield is set to a value.

I tried to solve the problem by myself, but it's not working, can you help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
                    if(document.getElementById("art").value == "test"){
                    document.getElementById("divDetails").style.display='block';
                    }
                    </script>
```

```html
<input type="text" name="art" id="art" value="" class="form-control" style="height: 3em; font-size: 9px;"> 
<div style="display: none" id="divDetails">Here is the hidden text</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your solution.

First you are running the JavaScript code before the HTML is rendered, creating the error in your demo.

Second, you are executing the JavaScript validation just once when you should actually always run it when the input value changes.

Try this instead:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  name="art"
  id="art"
  value=""
  class="form-control"
  style="height: 3em; font-size: 9px;"
  oninput="checkDetailsVisibility()"> 
<div
  style="display: none"
  id="divDetails">Here is the hidden text</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkDetailsVisibility() {
    if(document.getElementById("art").value == "test"){
      document.getElementById("divDetails").style.display='block';
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("divDetails").style.display='none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Every time that the value of the input changes, the function `checkDetailsVisibility` gets executed and either show or hide the desired div.

Answer (score 1):

What you have will only run once on execution, you need to check when the input is changed.

```
document.getElementById("art").addEventListener("input",()=>{
    if(document.getElementById("art").value == "test"){
        document.getElementById("divDetails").style.display='block';
    }
})
```

Comment: this solution also works perfect, thank you for your help.